# why the mesh going through each other

Tags: modifiers

I have a spiral curve made from the addon. And a normal plane with subdivision added. I have added array and curve modifier. The problem when i want to coil the plane its going inside each other. I just want my plane to be coil as the curve is.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The spiral has been scaled in object mode. Apply the scale on the spiral. (Ctrl+A)

Comment: @cegaton i apply still the same